# Are Jews allowed to pray on their knees?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, hashkafah-philosophy, avodah-zarah

If someone finds it a good way to have a concentration in pray while on his knees, can it be done? (Not talking about Amida/Sidur prayers, but talking with the creator.)

Comment: This is how Solomon is said to have prayed (1 Kings 8:54): קָ֞ם מִלִּפְנֵ֨י מִזְבַּ֤ח יְהוָה֙ מִכְּרֹ֣עַ עַל־בִּרְכָּ֔יו

Comment: IIRC meforshim on Shulchan Aruch Yore Dea 178 talk about this.

Answer (score -5):

Since praying on their knees is a distinct sign of Christianity (is it?), it is forbidden to resemble non-Jews in their conduct.

See [Rambam Avodah Zarah 11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.11?lang=bi):

> "אֵין הוֹלְכִין בְּחֻקּוֹת הָעוֹבְדֵי כּוֹכָבִים וְלֹא מִדַּמִּין לָהֶן לֹא בְּמַלְבּוּשׁ וְלֹא בְּשֵׂעָר וְכַיּוֹצֵא בָּהֶן"
>
> "**It is forbidden to follow the customs of the idolaters, or to imitate them** neither in dress nor in hair-trimming and like customs, for it is said: "And ye shall not walk in the customs of the nation which I cast out before you" (Lev. 20.23), and it is also said: "And in their customs shall ye not walk" (Ibid. 18.3), and it is, moreover, said: Then take heed to thyself that thou be not snared by following them" (Deut. 12.30)—all of which pertain to one subject admonishing them not to be like unto them. Forsooth an Israelite shall be separated from them, and be recognized by his clothes and in his conduct as he is different than they are in education and tendencies. For even so it is said: "And have set you apart from the peoples, that ye should be Mine" (Lev. 20.26)."

PS: *Thanks YaacovDeane*: The practice of praying on the knees is mentioned in the Scriptures. BUT It is important to stress, that even the practices that were "originally" Jewish and later adopted by other religions are forbidden to follow

Comment: Not sure about this

Comment: Besides, for Modeh Ani, some chasidim hold their hands in a gesture very very reminiscent of Christian prayer, lehavdil. It's not only allowed but is the minhag

Comment: @SAH Mentioned in the Talmud as the practice of Rava: רבא שדי גלימיה ופכר ידיה ומצלי (Shabbat 10a)

Comment: This conclusion that what Rambam is addressing is equated with the general concept of prayer on ones knees is simply wrong. Traditional Jewish practice in terms of one of the postures taken for prophetic prayer/meditation is crouching on knees with head at or between the knees.

Comment: For reference, see 1 Kings 18:42.

Comment: But the Christians stole it from us, no? If the Christians started bowing and bending during prayer we wouldn't cease doing this during the Amidah.

Comment: That was the reason of my question, are we allowed or not? for being like the way christians do. I think in judaism we have it, so we cannot stop something good because they do as us, want references

Comment: @YaacovDeane THis is exactly what the Torah prescribes us - once the idolaters start doing things we did, we're forbidden to continue to use those practices. Bringing examples from the first Temple is useless. The whole point of Rambam is we're forbidden to resemble the idolaters EVEN  performing our own traditions.

Comment: @SAH Please read my PS. Also please elaborate on your "about this".

Comment: @ezra we might, and in fact arguably that already happened. arguably the bowing we are supposed to do is the on the floor kind but it was stopped when Muslims took it on so we fake it nowadays.

Comment: @DoubleAA I actually seriously doubt that we stopped bowing to the floor because of the Muslims. It might have everything to do with the fact that people don't bow to the floor before kings anymore, especially in Europe. Kind of like how some people used to remove their shoes before the king in the Middle East, but in Europe wearing shoes before a king was crucial.

Comment: @ezra perhaps .

Comment: @AlBerko "THis is exactly what the Torah prescribes us - once the idolaters start doing things we did, we're forbidden to continue to use those practices. Bringing examples from the first Temple is useless. The whole point of Rambam is we're forbidden to resemble the idolaters EVEN performing our own traditions." Would be very interested to see where the Rambam says this.

Comment: @SAH I didn't say my comment was a Rambam's citation, however, BASED on that Rambam we stopped various practices once they were adopted by idolaters. Do you ask for an exact source for this claim?

Comment: @AlBerko Yes, please.